# add url for category with django 2

Tags: python, django, categories, django-2.0

I'm working on my blog page
basically the blog has category for split the same posts,
for this 
I made a class for category and made a relationship between the category and my post class like this :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Posts_image')
  title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  configure_slug = models.CharField(max_length=512)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=512,null=True,blank=True)
  content = HTMLField('Content')
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
  tags = TaggableManager()
  publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

after this I made this function

```
def blog_category(request):
  res_posts = Post.objects.all()
  category = request.POST.get('categories__name')
  if category:
    res_post = res_post.filter(
        Q(categories__name__icontains=category)).distinct()

  context = {
    'posts':res_posts,
  }
  return render(request, 'Blog/category-result.html', context)
```

I tell you how its works:
when the users click on the one of category title in the blog page
this functions start work and search how many posts has this category title and list them in the **category-result.html**

but this function doesn't work correctly
I think this code doesn't work correctly

```
category = request.POST.get('categories__name')
```

request.Post can't take the categories__name when user click

Can you help me for this problem???

Answer (score 0):

As you said the user *clicks* I'm assuming the category title links to a something like  `http://your.site/your-view?categories__name=selected-category`, if that's the case what you need to use is `request.GET` not `request.POST`.